# Find elements existing in both collections using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, intersection

Say I have two collections

```
int[] foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] bar = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
```

What would be the simplest way using linq to select values that exist in both collections?

i.e. a collection containing 2 and 4.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
int[] result = foo.Intersect(bar).ToArray();
```